# defining inequality of natural numbers by case-analysis

Tags: inequality, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

If I add to Peano Arithmetic a relation (predicate?) symbol $\leq$ and an axiom $\forall n\forall m(n\leq m \leftrightarrow n=m \lor S(n)\leq m)$, can I prove $\forall n\forall m(n\leq m \to n\leq S(m))$?

Related question: [How to compare Peano numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658727/how-to-compare-peano-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

You can see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566565/are-if-and-iff-interchangeable-in-definitions) for reference to the logical theory of *definition*.

In oder to add to a first-order language a new predicate symbol $P$, we have to introduce an axiom defining it.

The defining axiom must be : $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, where $\varphi$ is a formula of the "original" language, and thus must not contain the predicate $P$.

In first-order arithmetic with [Peano's axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) we can introduce the binary predicate (or *relation*) $<$ through the axiom :

> $n < m \leftrightarrow \exists z (m=n+S(z))$

and then :

> $n \le m \leftrightarrow n < m \lor n = m$.

With these abbreviations, we can prove :

> > $n \le m \leftrightarrow n < S(m)$.

See Stephen Cole Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0923891579) (1952) : $ ✳138a$, page 188.

---

---

*Proof*

For lemmas, I'll use the original Kleene's numeration; for Peano's axioms I'll call them $P1-P7$, following the order in Wiki's page.

Some preliminary *lemmas*:

$✳135b : 0 < S(n)$; proof from axioms $P3-P4$ : recursive axioms for sum.

$ ✳136 : 0 \le n$; proof by Induction on $n$, using $✳135b$.

$ ✳137 : n = 0 \lor (\exists m)(n = S(m))$; proof by cases from $✳136 : 0 < n \lor 0 = n$.

---

The following is an expanded version of the three-lines proof in Kleene's book of :

> $ ✳138a : n \le m \leftrightarrow n < S(m)$.

Proof :

**step 1**

$n < S(m) \leftrightarrow (\exists z)(S(m)=n + S(z))$ --- abbreviation

> [1] assume for $\exists$E : $S(m)=n+S(z)$;

$z = 0 \lor (\exists w)(z=S(w))$ --- from $✳137$

> > [1a] assume $z=0$

from [1] : $S(m)=n+S(0)$

$S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$ --- by $\lor$I

Thus : $c=0, S(m)=n+S(z) \vdash S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$ --- by $\exists$E.

> > [1b] assume $(\exists w)(z=S(w))$

In the same way, by $\exists$E, we prove : $(\exists w)(z=S(w)), S(m)=n+S(z) \vdash S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$.

From [1a] and [1b] follows (proof by cases and $\rightarrow$I) :

> $n < S(m) \rightarrow S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$.

=\=\=\=

> [2] assume $S(m)=n+S(0)$; by $\exists$I : $(\exists z)(S(m)=n+S(z))$;

also :  $(\exists w)(S(m)=n + S(S(w))) \vdash (\exists z)(S(m)=n+S(z))$.

Then $S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n + S(S(w))) \rightarrow (\exists z)(S(m)=n+S(z))$ --- proof by cases and $\rightarrow$I.

Thus:

> $S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n + S(S(w))) \rightarrow (n < S(m))$ --- abbreviation.

=\=\=\=

From [1] and [2] and $\leftrightarrow$I :

> > $n < S(m) \leftrightarrow S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n + S(S(w)))$

=\=\=\=

=\=\=\=

**step 2**

> [1] Assume : $S(m)=n+S(0)$;

it follows that : $S(m)=S(n+0)$, by axiom $P4$, and : $m=n+0$, by axiom $P2$, and $m=n$.

Thus : $S(m)=n+S(0) \rightarrow m=n$.

In the same way : $m=n \rightarrow S(m)=n+S(0)$.

> Thus, by $\leftrightarrow$I : $m=m \leftrightarrow S(m)=n+S(0)$.

=\=\=\=

> [2] Assume $(\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$;

assume for $\exists$E : $S(m)=n+S(S(w))$; then $S(m)=S(n+S(w))$, and so : $m=n+S(w)$ and finally : $(\exists w)(m=n+S(w))$, by $\exists$I.

Thus :

$(\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w))) \rightarrow  (\exists w)(m=n+S(w))$.

In the same way : $(\exists w)(m=n+S(w)) \rightarrow (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$

Finally :

> $(\exists w)(m=n+S(w)) \leftrightarrow (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$ --- by $\leftrightarrow$I.

=\=\=\=

=\=\=\=

**step 3**

From step 1 we have : $n < S(m) \leftrightarrow S(m)=n+S(0) \lor (\exists w)(S(m)=n + S(S(w)))$.

From step 2 we have : $(\exists w)(m=n+S(w)) \leftrightarrow (\exists w)(S(m)=n+S(S(w)))$.

We need also the fact that : $S(m)=n+S(0)=S(n+0)=S(n) \leftrightarrow m=n$.

Using *tautologies* [see $✳29a/b$, page 116] : $A \leftrightarrow B \vdash (A \lor C) \leftrightarrow (B \lor C)$ and $A \leftrightarrow B \vdash (C \lor A) \leftrightarrow (C \lor B)$, we have :

> $n < S(m) \leftrightarrow m=n \lor (\exists w)(m=n+S(w))$

and finally, with the abbreviation for $n < m$ :

> > $n < S(m) \leftrightarrow m=n \lor n < m$

which is :

> > > $n < S(m) \leftrightarrow n \le m$.

---

---

*Notes*

**(A)** Equivalently, we can start with :

> $n \le m \leftrightarrow \exists z (m=n+z)$

and then define :

> $n < m \leftrightarrow n \le m \land n \ne m$.

---

**(B)** We can instead use $<$ as a primitive symbols, adding to the usual (firts-oder) Peano's axioms the following recursive definition of $<$ :

> $\forall x \lnot (x < 0)$
>
> $\forall x \forall y (x < S(y) \leftrightarrow (x < y \lor x = y))$.

Comment: My question was, can we prove it from my definition of inequality.

Comment: It's perfectly legal in an axiom.